# autocomplete check when focus is lost

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, jquery-autocomplete

How do I ensure the value in the input field always has a value from the source only?

For example, if in the source I have

```
source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
```

which is database driven as the actual script is:

```
source: "get_json.aspx";
```

and in the input field I type just "**cold**", how do I stop this from happening?

How do I ensure that the value exists in the source when focus is lost from the input field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should bind to proper event. I think you should bind to [close event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-close). then check [value of input](http://api.jquery.com/val/) contains element [in array](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). Else you should make input empty again using [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/). I tested it myself locally and it does the trick.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        var inputValue = $( "#tags" ).val();
        var idx = jQuery.inArray(inputValue, availableTags);
        if (idx == -1) {
            $( "#tags" ).val("");           
        }
    }
});
```

**P.S:** I did some more testing and I think you should bind it to another event instead. Because when you tab to navigation bar it does not work. I think you should bind to [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event instead.

**The improved code =>**

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});

$( "#tags").blur(function() {
    var inputValue = $( "#tags" ).val();
    var idx = jQuery.inArray(inputValue, availableTags);
    if (idx == -1) {
        $( "#tags" ).val("");           
    }
});
```

**json to array =>**

**json.txt:**

```
[{"id":1,"value":"ActionScript"},{"id":2,"value":"AppleScript"},{"id":3,"value":"Asp"},{"id":4,"value":"BASIC"},{"id":5,"value":"C"},{"id":6,"value":"C++"},{"id":7,"value":"Clojure"},{"id":8,"value":"COBOL"},{"id":9,"value":"ColdFusion"},{"id":10,"value":"Erlang"},{"id":11,"value":"Fortran"},{"id":12,"value":"Groovy"},{"id":13,"value":"Haskell"},{"id":14,"value":"Java"},{"id":15,"value":"JavaScript"},{"id":16,"value":"Lisp"},{"id":17,"value":"Perl"},{"id":18,"value":"PHP"},{"id":19,"value":"Python"},{"id":20,"value":"Ruby"},{"id":21,"value":"Scala"},{"id":21,"value":"Scheme"}]
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var LIMIT = 10;
    $.getJSON("json.json", function(data) {
        var autocomplete = $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var i=0;
                var result = [];
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    // value.value.search(/request.term/i);
                    var idx = value.value.toLowerCase().indexOf( request.term.toLowerCase() );
                    if (idx >= 0) {
                        result.push(value.value);
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i === LIMIT) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                response(result);
            }
        });

        $( "#tags").blur(function() {
            var inputValue = $( "#tags" ).val();
            var clear = true;
            $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
                if (value.value == inputValue) {
                    clear = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (clear) {
                $( "#tags" ).val("");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What if the source is a url, which returns json?

Comment: Then you should check if that source contains text of input value.  In my opinion if the source isn't too big you should use array to avoid round-trips to the server.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to avoid.  But I don't know how to get the source into an array to avoid the round trip...

Comment: what server-side language are you using? And from where are you getting your data? From your site?

Comment: I am using asp.net and yes, it is our in-house company server.  The data is coming from an ms sql server query.

Comment: Oops I know a lot of programming languages, but I don't know asp.net :$. But an array is just a very simple structure. Just loop over the elements in the sql database and add them to the appending it to your string(which looks like array).

Comment: I've done all the server-side stuff and I have a json array which the asp.net page returns in the form of source: "get_json.aspx".  I don't know how to put this array into a standard JavaScript array or how to extract the array from within .autocomplete?

Comment: @oshirowanen I think it would be easier if we just chat => http://4827315.speeqe.com/

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is on document.ready, have an .ajax function which gets the data from the database, makes a clientside level array which can be used in other parts of the javascript including the close event of autocomplete.  I am hoping there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Alfred:  I tried your new script, and for some reason it always clears the input field as on blur?

Comment: @oshirowanen you are completely right lol. I only checked that it did get data :P. I will update my code. Hang on one second!

Comment: I finished it. stupid me. It isn't a pure array anymore so I needed to update some parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      autoFocus: true,
      selectFirst: true,
      //clear value on lost focus
      change: function (ev, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
      }
    })
```